# How can I efficiently render many pages of SwiftUI to pdf?

Tags: ios, swiftui, pdfkit, pdf-rendering

I am trying to create a PDF document from hundreds of pages of a SwiftUI view's.  Currently my approach is the following. This works fine but it is quite slow.  Was wondering if there is a better way of doing this either by using UIKit or some other method?

```
@MainActor
func renderPages() async {
    let pathComponent = "example.pdf"
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
    var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 500)
    guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
        return
    }
    for pageIndex in pageIndices {
        pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content:
             MySwiftUIView(index: pageIndex)
        )
        renderer.render { size, myContext in
            myContext(pdf)
        }
        pdf.endPDFPage()
    }
    pdf.closePDF()
    self.url = url
}
```